# How would I estimate the partial width for the decay of upsilon meson into an electron-positron pair?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, quarks, mesons, leptons

I cam across a question that stated the total decay width for the phi meson was 4300 kev and the partial decay of it into an electron-positron pair was 1.3kev. How would I estimate the partial width for the decay of upsilon meson into an electron-poistron pair knowing that its total decay width is 54kev? I know it must be small as strong force would dominate but is there a way i could make a good guess, or is it a case of just being able to say its *small*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the widths from [this](https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-1573(89)90074-4) review, [image]
so the width to $e^+e^-$ of both the $\phi$ and the $\Upsilon$ must be something like 12/9 keV ~ 1.3 keV, somewhat higher for the latter. The one for the $\Upsilon$ is close to the BR of the PDG for that mode.

The horizontality of the line reflects this is  the same one-photon exchange diagram (up to quark charges squared) where $|\psi(0)/M_V|$ does not vary much, empirically confirmed. That is, the Van Royen--Weisskopf width for negatively charged quark vector quarkonia is $\Gamma(V\to e^+e^-)= \frac{16\pi}{9} \alpha^2 \left | {\psi(0)\over M_V}\right |^2$.

- PS If you *really* wished to go theory-berserk, you might look at [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1140/epjc/s10052-019-7158-9), estimating a width of 1.27 keV.