# If a $J/\psi$ decays to an electron-positron pair 5% of the time, how often would a $\phi$ meson decay to a electron-positron pair?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, mesons

I know the mass of $J/\psi$ to be 3097 mev and the mass of phi to be 1018 mev. I know that $J/\psi$ decays to electron and positron 5% of the time. I also know the full width of j/psi to be 0.092mev and that the phi meson lives 50 times longer than $J/\psi$. My professor claims that if I am given that info and can draw the feynman diagrams for both interactions then it should be possible to make an estimate on how often the phi meson decays to electron-positron pair too. But I dont understand how this can done.

I have drawn both diagrams (c-cbar or s-sbar to electron and positron with photon boson between). I also know the following formulas:

```
total width =  \hbar / \tau
```

where tau is the decay time of the particle. I also know that the branching fraction is given as:

```
BF = partial width / total width
```

Im not sure how one could estimate the branching fraction of phi to electron-positron pair.

Comment: Related post by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/789796/2451

Comment: [Linked](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/787530/66086). How do you compare to J/ψ instead of $\Upsilon$?

Comment: Try MathJax: https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the mate of your [previous question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/787530/66086), with a small difference: the virtual photon producing the $e^+ e^-$ pair couples twice as strongly to $c\bar c$ as to $s\bar s$, so, squaring the diagram,
$$
\Gamma( \phi\to e^+ e^-) = \Gamma( \psi\to e^+ e^-)/4,
$$
while (the BF is closer to 6% than to 5%)
$$
\Gamma( \psi\to e^+ e^-)\approx 0.06 ~\Gamma_{\psi ~total} \approx  5.6 ~\hbox {keV}. $$

Hence,
$$\Gamma( \phi\to e^+ e^-)\approx 1.4 ~\hbox{ keV}, $$
compared to the PDG value of 1.3 keV.

The corresponding BF is about 3 $\cdot 10^{-4}$. Your professor claims well.